# Why does saying the word "fuck" help vent frustration?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, profanity

I have observed a good number of people muttering "fuckfuckfuck" under their breath when nervous. It somehow seems to vent the frustration out, and calm the person down. Why does this happen?

I found a few articles such as [this](https://newrepublic.com/article/63921/what-the-f) that describe how saying the word triggers parts of our brains and all that. But is there a any linguistic reason?

I have noticed that saying euphemisms such as "heck" or "fudge" also helps, but not as much as the f-word itself. Does this have something to do with the combination of a fricative and a velar plosive?

Comment: Does 'hell' help at all for you? If it helps, then the fricatives and plosives can't be the only relevant factor.

Comment: It does. There are a lot of such words that help, I am sure. But I have specific questions about this word.

Comment: Well, it's not a phenomenon specific to this word. We know that strongly tabooed words in general help vent strong emotion, IIRC from my undergrad. More literature on that could make a good answer. Another interesting question that overlaps more with your intended one might be whether there are phonological patterns to tabooed words, particularly those used to vent. (e.g. *heck*, *shit*, *fuck* are all one syllable with a short vowel moving from a voiceless fricative to a voiceless plosive. But I suspect counterexamples would defeat most patterns we could spot, and to that I say, *tabernac'!*)

Comment: Hmm, but if something like _hooyada_ is a swear word, then I guess our pattern is restricted to a subset of English words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is reported in research by Stephens, Atkins & Kingston and Stephens & Umland that swearing alleviates pain. At present it's a mystery why, but one chain of reasoning is that it results in release of adrenaline, because swearing triggers a fight-or-flight response. It has nothing to do with the phonetic shape of the word (did you know that *hooyada was* is a swear? Not in English). Some uses may be quasi-conventionalized, especially the triplicated ones. S*3, F*3 crap*3 are relatively common in some (younger) circles, damn*3 maybe, but I've never heard C*3,B*3, MF*3, CS*3 or SOB*3. There may be an articulatory underpinning to the low or zero frequency of B*3, and length is no doubt at work in the fact that you don't triplicate SOB.

Comment: What is cs*3? Most of the others I could just about make out. And are you able to elaborate on *hooyada*?

Comment: cs=cock sucker. Hooyada is Somali, meaning "your mother" and *was* is a verb in the imperative. Uttering just the noun may have a similar effect, I've been told.